# Twitter Bootstrap Scrollspy: wrong item highlighted

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple page with scroll spy in it. It works quite well when scrolling, but when I click on a link in the navigation panel, previous one is highlighted (although the page scrolls correctly). Also, when I remove class="navbar" from the first div, scrolling also starts to malfunction a little (highlights trigger not in right time). HTML is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="./bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbarExample" class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#abc">abc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#def">def</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ghi">ghi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-target="#navbarExample" data-spy="scroll" style="width: 200px; height: 120px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <h4 id="abc">abc</h4>
        <div>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
        <h4 id="def">def</h4>
        <div>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
        <h4 id="ghi">ghi</h4>
        <div>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I also have an issue like this, move your data attribute to the body and it'll work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script src="./jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="./bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.css" />
</head>
<body data-target="#navbarExample" data-spy="scroll">
    <div id="navbarExample" class="navbar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#abc">abc</a></li>
            <li><a href="#def">def</a></li>
            <li><a href="#ghi">ghi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 120px; overflow-y: scroll">
        <h4 id="abc">abc</h4>
        <div>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
        <h4 id="def">def</h4>
        <div>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
        <h4 id="ghi">ghi</h4>
        <div>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Now the last link is always highlighted. It is div that is actually being scrolled, not body.

Comment: Try by wrapping your ul.nav with <div class="navbar-inner">